# Can't find Ubuntu

Tags: downloads

I donated $9 and downloaded Ubuntu. Once my computer rebooted, I can't find it anywhere.  I did not burn anything on a CD. Is there anything I can do to access it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Open the web browser that you used to download Ubuntu and check your web browser's download history to find the Ubuntu iso file that you downloaded there. In Firefox click the down arrow icon **⭳** on the right side of the Firefox toolbar and select *Show All Downloads*, then right-click the Ubuntu iso file that you downloaded and select *Open Containing Folder*.

That's where the Ubuntu iso file will be unless you have deleted it or moved it to a different folder. If you have deleted it, you can download the Ubuntu iso file again without paying anything, and because Ubuntu is free software you can also download the Ubuntu iso file as many times as you like without paying anything.